# how to crop the image using css only with justify-content left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to crop the image using display and justify-content in CSS as per the screen size. The image look like below, between the vector header  and start of the image some padding is there. This image looks fine when it is displaying in the desktop based screen, but in mobile based screen it is not displaying fine. I am using the below CSS to crop the image in my web page.

**Image Looks**

[image]

**CSS Code**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="/header.png">
</div>
```

After cropping the image using CSS, the image look like below

[image]

But I also want to crop in the beginning of Vector Header based on the screen size like below. Is there is any way in CSS to do this with the existing CSS code.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your suggestion and advice.

Comment: negative margin-left ?

Comment: but it will add spacing before the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `background-position` property

```css
#header { 
      background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RIPB.png'); 
      background-position: -30px 0px; 
      width: 200px; 
      height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="header" />
```